# Is parallel merge sort always worth it?

Tags: sorting, parallel-processing, mergesort

So, I know that if I have n number of data and p number of processors, an algorithm like mergesort will split this data in n/p data per processor, and run the sequential sorting algorithm for each sub section of the data. It will then put them back together ( sort them ).
What I am wondering is if this is always faster than simply using the sequential mergesort on n?
I see the time complexity decreasing since we operate on n/p data but also increasing since we have the additional time used for the parallel operations...

I am thinking that if I set up the two equations, they should look something like this:

N/p log2 N/p + 2N-2 = N* log2 N

where the left side is the parallel algorithm and the right side the non parallel one. Is this correct and how would I go about solving it?

Comment: There is a nice little graph here which shows a benchmark of different implementations: http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/parallel-in-place-merge-sort/240169094

Comment: So I guess there must be a point at which one is more efficient than the other and vice-versa So, would the equation above be correct to find the point at which one case becomes the other? ( And I am not sure how to solve that anyways... tried several things, non of which game me anything that made sense :/ )

Comment: What do you mean by "time used for the parallel operations"?  Any why is it related to N but not p?

Comment: By time used for parallel operations I mean time used to re-merge together the various pieces of n/p data sorted by each processor, and I made it depend on N because when I merge back together the data sorted by each processor, the time it will take to do it depends on the length of the pieces of data I am merging. ( I think.. )

Answer (score 0):

Take the simple case of 2 processors.  For simplicity (and since you don't say otherwise), I'll assume shared memory.

The sequential case will, in sequence:

1. Sort one half
2. Sort the other half
3. Merge the two halves

The parallel case will perform the same steps, but do steps 1 & 2 in parallel; the only added work is any overhead in managing the processes/threads.

As the number of processors goes up, the time it will take to do the parallel part will diminish, speeding thing up until it is overtaken by the overhead of managing the parallel bits.

Comment: I understand why the parallel part should always decrease, but comparing its time complexity to the simple mergesort of n data, when does it become "worth it" to use parallel. Yes, It is taking me less to the mergesort of n/p but it is also taking me more to merge the sorted pieces back ( O(2N-2) ).

Comment: While it may not show up in the O() notation (since O(N) is subsumed by O(N log N)), both algorithms do the exact same work merging; the parallel version is not taking more time to merge.